# TypeError: this.views_src[0] is undefined in openerp when returning view?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I have an inherited module and I am trying to return

```
    view_ref = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'product', 'product_product_tree_view')
    view_id = view_ref and view_ref[1] or False
    return {
   'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
   'name': 'Draft Product',
   'res_model': 'product.product',
   'view_type': 'form',
   'view_id': view_id,
   'view_mode': 'tree',
   'target': 'current',
   'nodestroy': True,
```

}

at the end of product inherited write method. But it throws an error

> TypeError: this.views_src[0] is undefined

I am fed up doing this for a long time.. any help or workaround is appreciated.... I actually want after editing the form view to be returned to tree view.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The following code is an example of how to return a tree view:

```
return {
        'name':_("Name desired"),
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'view_id': False,
        'view_type': 'tree',
        'res_model': 'your model',
        'res_id': read_ids, \\\instead of read_ids, you must pass the desired record ids\\\
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'nodestroy': True,
        'target': 'new',
        'domain': "[('id','in',%s)]" %(read_ids),
        'context': context
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Thanks Yaseen.... I am a super newbie in openerp... It would be great if you could help me with getting the "read_ids" in above code

Comment: is that the corresponding product id??

Comment: Yes...it should be the corresponding record's id....you can create a list named read_ids or whatever you like and then append the necessary ids to that list.

Comment: Thank you Yaseen however I have given a current editing product id there but it still throws the same error

Comment: Where in database can I find the read_id can you give me the column name and table name... would be really help full

Comment: Well, You could use the browse method and get the desired product id and append it to a list or pass it directly to the res_id in the returning view.

Comment: And read_id is just a custom list i created for my purpose it's not a general thing! You could create your own list and append the required product ids to it and pass that list to res_id in the returning view.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `views` key to solve the problem.

To open the list view of products:

```
{
    "type": "ir.actions.act_window",
    "res_model": "product.product",
    "views": [[False, "list"]],
    "target": "current",
}
```

I know, it is too late to answer it, but I hope someone will find it helpful.